# Rust `Vec` - cannot borrow `Vec` as immutable inside `impl` method (error[E0502])

Tags: vector, rust, borrowing

There are a lot of answers for the questions about Rust's `error[E0502]`, but I can't really understand one particular case. I have a `struct` and it's `impl` method that goes like this:

```rust
struct Test {
  test_vec: Vec<i32>,
}

impl Test {
  // other methods...

  fn test(&mut self) -> i32 {
    self.test_vec.swap(0, self.test_vec.len() - 1);

    // other operations...
  }
}
```

Trying to compile that immediately results in error:

> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.test_vec` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

```sh
self.test_vec.swap(0, self.test_vec.len() - 1);
------------- ----    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
|             |
|             mutable borrow later used by call
mutable borrow occurs here
```

Can anyone please explain why? It doesn't really look like I'm trying to borrow `self.test_vec` there, I'm passing the `usize` type result of a `len()` call. On the other hand:

```rust
fn test(&mut self) -> i32 {
  let last_index = self.test_vec.len() - 1;

  self.test_vec.swap(0, last_index);

  // other operations...
}
```

Using temporary variable, it works as expected, makes me thinking that `len()` call is somehow evaluated *after* it gets to to the `swap`, and thus being borrowed? Am I not seeing something because of the syntax sugar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think of this in the way the compiler does. When you write:

```
self.test_vec.swap(0, self.test_vec.len() - 1);
```

What the compiler sees:

```
let temp1 = &mut self.test_vec;      // Mutable borrow of self.test_vec
let temp2 = &self.test_vec;          // (ERROR!) Shared borrow of self.test_vec for use on getting the length
let temp3 = Vec::len(temp2) - 1; 
Vec::swap(temp1, 0, temp3);
```

As you can see, you are borrowing `self.test_vec` mutably first, and then trying to get the length, which is another borrow. Since the first borrow is mutable and still in effect, the second borrow is illegal.

When you use a temporary variable, you are effectively reordering your borrows and since `self.test_vec.len()` terminates the borrow before the next mutable borrow, there are no conflicts.

You can argue the compiler should be able to see that your code can be correct (if interpreted with in the right way), but the compiler is clearly not smart enough yet to do so.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But still, why during the `self.test_vec.len() - 1` borrowing *actually* occurs? I would naturally expect that order of operations would first calculate the vector's length and then call the function as `Vec::swap(&mut self.test_vec, 0, x - 1)`.

Comment: This problem has basically nothing to do with `Vec::swap()`. First a temporary variable (that we can't see) is made for holding `&mut self.test_vec` is made, then one for the `0`, then one for the `self.test_vec.len() - 1`. This might not be 100% accurate, but if you think of it this way, it is obvious that the first temp variable is still in scope when the third is made. I'll edit my answer to show this.

Comment: That makes it clearer. I've checked by passing a mutable reference to a function, and compiler fairly complained that double mutable borrow is illegal - which is understandable. Thank you for taking time to describe that behavior!